# An ARRAYFORMULA formula that adds but resets the result before a certain number is exceeded

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

Accumulates the numeric values in the left column and returns them to the cells in the right column of the same row.
However, it should not exceed 6.
If the value exceeds 6 when added, the accumulated value is initialized and added again.
Repeat this process.

I'd like to get this to work with the spreadsheet's formula function. But this is too complicated...

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your numeric values in F2 downwards as shown, enter the following in G2:

```
=scan(,F2:F,lambda(acc,arr,if(arr="",,if(acc+arr<6,acc+arr,arr))))
```